# Заменить %20 на пробел

Tags: javascript, php

Народ всем привет! Есть импут через который проходят поисковые запросы, когда в импут вбивается 1 слово поиск работает корректно но когда 2 и более слов то вместо пробела слова разделяются %20 и соответственно поиск перестает работать.

Импут:

```
    <?php if ($this->config->get('layout_search')) { ?>
    <div class="eb-toolbar__item eb-toolbar__item--search hide" data-eb-toolbar-search-wrapper>
        <div id="eb-toolbar-search" class="eb-toolbar__search">
            <form class="eb-toolbar__search-form" method="post" action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php');?>">
                <div class="eb-toolbar__search-box">
                    <input type="text" name="query" class="eb-toolbar__search-input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="— <?php echo JText::_('COM_EASYBLOG_TOOLBAR_PLACEHOLDER_SEARCH');?>" value="<?php echo $this->html('string.escape', $query);?>" />
                    <?php echo $this->html('form.action', 'search.query');?>

                    <div class="eb-toolbar__search-filter-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" style="border-color: #f0f0f0 !important;">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="eb-filter-select-group">
                    <?php echo $categoryDropdown; ?>
                    <div class="eb-filter-select-group__drop"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Подскажите как сделать так что бы генерировался пробел а не %20 в поисковой строке.

Comment: js: `encodeURIComponent('str with spaces')`

Comment: Покажите php код, который обрабатывает введенное значение. В приведенном сейчас примере есть только формирование страницы с запросом и подстановка некой, не известной ранее, переменной `$query` в значение input. Если в $query таки содержится строка и она например в инпут попадает с %20, то значит, что то в this->html ее так перекодирует (либо что то выполнило это ранее). Да, из браузера на сервер пробел передается как %20, но php сам декодирует его, когда кладет в $_POST['query']. Если в скрипте при этом оказывается опять кодированное значение, значит ваш собственный код в php сам его кодирует

Comment: Вот весь код: https://yadi.sk/d/1nAcVXWEmTo8gg не нашла способа залить куда-то еще.

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот такой функцией воспользоваться для преобразования (если в JS идёт обработка):

```
function urldecode(str) {
   return decodeURIComponent((str+'').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
}
```

Либо если PHP то функция [urldecode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: Обработка идет в PHP вы можете написать код каким он должен быть у этого элемента? <input type="text" name="query" class="eb-toolbar__search-input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="— <?php echo JText::_('COM_EASYBLOG_TOOLBAR_PLACEHOLDER_SEARCH');?>" value="<?php echo $this->html('string.escape', $query);?>" />